# How to include directory extension into access token in azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created directory extension and assigned data for it but when I add it in Token configuration but it still not include in access token so how to include directory extension in Azure AD ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to add custom extension attribute in azure AD.**

Create a new app registration like below

**Azure AD Portal>Azure Active Directory>App registrations**

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/QwylSSx.png)]

Create custom extension attribute using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)  and login graph explorer with global admin account.

You can get the application object ID like below

**Azure Portal>Azure Active Directory>App Registration>Select your App**

[image]

Execute the code in graph explorer like below

```
 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<AppregistrationObjectID>
```

Modify the code to create the custom extension

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<AppregistrationObjectID>/extensionProperties
   {
"name": "CustomAttribute",
"dataType": "string",
"targetObjects": [
"User",
"Group"
]
}
```

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/dYVpC8M.png)]

Add the custom attribute to user object like below

```
 PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<UserObjectID>
    {
    "extension_47c8caba8d924ac9a0f159b0dcc8d4c7_CustomAttribute": "Demo"
    }
```

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/kmKPcmg.png)]

You can get the user object ID like below

**Azure Portal>Azure Active Directory>Users>Select your Global Admin user**

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/moB3C2D.png)]

Added custom attribute in access token

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/5BDo5FJ.png)]

Finally added custom extension attribute like below

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/ILmyiTd.png)]